# Checkbox data isn't being stored to DB

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having a problem not being able to upload answers in checkbox to DB.

I have a checkbox in my form that a user can check multiple boxes or maybe choose one or none. I am trying to using implode method to upload the answers to DB and this is what my code looks now.

**ProductController.php**

```
public function store(ProductRequest $request)
{
    $product = new Product;
    $product->user_id = $request->user()->id;
    $product->name = $request->name;
    if($request->has('allergy[]')) {
        $allergy = $request->allergy;
        $string = implode(",", $allergy);
        $product->allergy = $string;
    }

    $product->save();
    return redirect('product/create')->with('message', 'Your answer has been uploaded.');
}
```

**register.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{ url('/product') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-group">
                                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        <p><label>menu<br>
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
                                            </label></p>                                            
                                        <p><label>allergy<br>
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="allergy[]" value="1"> apple
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="allergy[]" value="2"> orange
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="allergy[]" value="3"> banana                                                    
                                            </label></p>
                                       
                                        <p><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">register</button></p>
                                    </form>
```

No error is showing after pressing register button but there's no data stored in DB when I check it. "allergy" column in DB is like charset(255) utf8mb4_unicode_ci NULLABLE.

I appreciate if you could tell me what I'm doing wrong or what I should do. Any help would be appreciated as I have tried multiple methods with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to check if the value of `allergy` has a string representation of an array, as the value will be presented to you in array format if it was sent using array notation. Due to this, your `if` check is failing:

```
if ($request->has('allergy')) {
    $product->allergy = implode(',' $request->get('allergy'));
}
```

Will correctly set the value of `$product->allergy` to the comma separated string you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for you advice. I checked and now the data is being stored to DB.
Thank you so much!

Comment: I was hoping if I could ask you one more question. When I want to do the visa vice versa, am I doing it right in the following code? 
```
public function index()
    {
        $products = Auth::user()->products()->get();

        $allergy = $products->allergy;
        $products->allergy = explode(',', $allergy);

        return view('product.show')->with(['products' => $products]);
    }
```

Comment: @toyop Yes. That'll work fine. Keep in mind you have to set the `checked` property of the checkbox if the value exists in your `allergy` array. Something like `@if (in_array(1, $product->allergy))  checked @endif`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm relieved to know that I'm doing it right. Also I very much appreciate  your additional advice. It really helped!